# What is the value of weierstrass $\wp$-function at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

Choosing the lattice $L=[1, \sqrt{-2}]$, what is the value of $\wp(0)$?

The definition of the Weierstrass $\wp$ function for the lattice $L$ is
$$
\wp(z;L) = \frac{1}{z^2} + \sum_{\omega \in L - \{ 0 \}} \bigg(\frac{1}{(z - \omega)^2} - \frac{1}{\omega^2}\bigg) \tag{w} \label{w}
.$$

##### My attempts

I tried to plug $z=0$, but the resulting series does not make sense. I thought about the correct way to define the value of the $\wp$ function for the lattice $L$ at $z=0$. But I couldn't figure that out either.

##### Background

In Cox's book "primes of the form x^2 + ny^2", according to **Theorem 10.14**, if $\alpha \in \Bbb C - \Bbb Z$, and $L$ is a lattice on the complex plane, then the condition $$\alpha L \subset L$$ implies that $\wp(\alpha z)$ is equal to a rational function of $\wp(z)$, i.e. $\wp(\alpha z) = \frac{A(\wp(z))}{B(\wp(z))}$, and degrees satisfy $\deg(A(x)) = \deg(B(x)) + 1 = N(\alpha)$.

So for the lattice we have chosen, and $\alpha = \sqrt{-2}$, we deduce that $\wp(\sqrt{-2} z) = \frac{A(\wp(z))}{B(\wp(z))}$.
Since $N(\sqrt{-2}) = 2$, in this case, the theorem tells us that $\deg(A(x)) = \deg(B(x)) + 1 = 2$.
By dividing $B(x)$ by $A(x)$, we can write this as

\begin{equation} 
\wp(\sqrt{-2} z) = a\wp(z) + b + \frac{1}{c \wp(z) +d} \tag{10.21}\label{10.21}
\end{equation}

where $a$ and $c$ are non-zero complex numbers.Then the book, on page 194, says

> Now that the constants $a$ and $b$ appearing in \eqref{10.21} are the unique constants such that $\wp(\sqrt{-2}z) - a \wp(z) - b$ is zero when $z = 0$.

This sentence is a bit hard for me to understand.

First, $z=0$ is assumed for the weirstrass function, but I do not know how to evaluate the weirstrass $\wp$ function, namely the series \eqref{w} at $0$. Directly substituting $z=0$ is certainly not valid, since ${1 \over z^2} = \frac{1}{0^2}$ is not defined.

Second, assuming the value $\wp(0)$ is well defined and found, \eqref{10.21} can be written as $\wp(0) = a \wp(0) + b + \frac{1}{ c \wp(0) + d}$. Even with this assumption, I am still puzzled by the quoted statement, i.e. $\wp(0) - a \wp(0) - b = 0$ for the constants $a$ and $b$ appearing in \eqref{10.21}, and constants $a$ and $b$ are the only values for which the equation holds.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can explain this. (My background is lacking, so it would be nice if you could provide the proposition used so that I can refer to it)

Comment: Doesn't it have a pole at $z=0$? (and shouldn't $1/\omega$ be $1/\omega^2$?)

Comment: "The Weierstrass ℘-function is an even elliptic function of order N=2 with a double pole at each lattice point and no other poles," says https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_functions#Weierstrass_zeta_function

Comment: But what is its values at its poles (or how to define these values)?

Comment: Do you know what *pole* means? If you're thinking of this as a function with values in the extended complex plane, then the value is $\infty$. This is a *meromorphic* function on the torus (or doubly-periodic *meromorphic* function on $\Bbb C$).

Comment: Thanks. I can roughly recall that the value of functions at a pole of kth order is the limit $\lim_{x\to p} (x - p)^k f(x)$. This seems to make more sense to me.

Comment: I think you are confusing "value" with "residue". The value of $1/z$ at $z=0$ is infinity; that's what it means, to have a pole. The residue of $1/z$ at zero is $1$, as given by that limit formula you have written.

Comment: I see that my last comment is not correct. The value of function $\wp(x)$ is unbounded near its pole, and so the value is infinity.

Comment: Since this infinity, $$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{1}{c \wp(z)+d} = 0.$$ The values $a$ and $b$ are the unique values such that $\lim_{z\to 0} \wp(\sqrt{-2} z) - a \wp(z) - b = 0$